# Prevent Firefox from stealing focus from i3 autostart config

Tags: firefox, window-manager, i3

I tried i3 `no_focus` and `focus` but it's not working for Firefox only.

My i3 config:

```
exec i3-msg workspace 1
no_focus [class="Firefox"]
exec --no-startup-id i3-msg 'workspace 1; exec /usr/bin/google-chrome'
exec --no-startup-id i3-msg 'workspace 1; exec /usr/bin/firefox'
exec i3-msg "[class=Google-chrome] focus"
```

I need `google-chrome` to be focused on startup.

I found a related one but it's not useful: [Prevent Firefox from taking focus when opening link in other application : i3wm](https://www.reddit.com/r/i3wm/comments/5o378t/prevent_firefox_from_taking_focus_when_opening/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`no_focus` setting won't work if your application is the first one on a workspace. From [i3 User's Guide](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#no_focus):

> `no_focus` will also be ignored for the first window on a workspace as
> there shouldn’t be a reason to not focus the window in this case. This
> allows for better usability in combination with `workspace_layout`.

One way to achieve what you want is to separate startup of this applications to make sure that Chromium will be launched last:

```
exec --no-startup-id firefox
exec --no-startup-id sleep 3 && chromium-browser
```

Comment: but this will always open browser windows in workspace 1 @diffy

Comment: @AkhilJ, edited config - removed workspace assignment. That way both applications will open on your default workspace 1 only at startup.

Comment: is it possible to make it in ```tabbed``` mode ? @diffy